# Is 毎X毎X a pattern that generalizes for anything that has a 毎X form?

Tags: words, morphology

Can you use the 毎X毎X pattern (indicating emphasis) for anything that would take 毎X? Circumstantial evidence suggests this should work: 毎日毎日 is clearly a thing, [this post](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13244537608?__ysp=5q%2BO5pmp5q%2BO5pmp) uses 毎晩毎晩, so one would assume it generalizes - but it doesn't hurt to be sure!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can say 毎日毎日, 毎朝毎朝, 毎晩毎晩, 毎度毎度, 毎回毎回, 毎週毎週, and even 毎学期毎学期, 毎ターン毎ターン, 毎セット毎セット and so on.

Basically these are emphatic versions, but note that this pattern usually has a negative overtone, like the speaker is irritated by or bored of the repetition. For example, 毎日毎日練習して上達したいです sounds a little unnatural to me.